# How to estimate the following integral: $\int_0^1 \frac{1-\cos x}{x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus

> How to estimate the following integral?
>   $$
> \int_0^1 \frac{1-\cos x}{x}\,dx
> $$

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i did. i got sin^2x/ (x)(1+cosx) and then simplified into sinx/x and sinx/(1+cosx) and now im lost :(

Answer (score 4):

First note that the integral exists since $$0 \leq \dfrac{1-\cos(x)}x = \dfrac{2 \sin^2(x/2)}x \leq \dfrac{x}2$$ Hence, the integral is between $0$ and $1/4$. To compute the integral, proceed as follows. We have
$$\cos(x) = 1 - \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \dfrac{x^4}{4!} \mp = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \dfrac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
Hence,
$$1-\cos(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{2!} - \dfrac{x^4}{4!} + \dfrac{x^6}{6!} \pm = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} \dfrac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} $$
This gives us
$$\dfrac{1-\cos(x)}x = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} \dfrac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k)!} $$
Now lets get back to the integral.
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \dfrac{1-\cos(x)}x dx & = \int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1}\dfrac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k)!} dx = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k)!}\int_0^1 x^{2k-1} dx\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k)!} \cdot \dfrac1{2k}
\end{align}

Comment: can you show us step by steps??cause im confused :(

Comment: Once you have this you can use the alternating series test to find a bound for the error in approximating by the $n$th partial sum.

Comment: you guys are so smart lol

Comment: @parker Have added the intermediate details.

Comment: @parker In the summation take the first $4$ terms, i.e., $$\dfrac1{2 \cdot 2!} - \dfrac1{4 \cdot 4!} + \dfrac1{6 \cdot 6!} - \dfrac1{8 \cdot 8!}$$ to get an accuracy of $1e-5$.

Comment: thank you so much for the help

Comment: i get .02398117146 and how is it possible to get an accuracy of 10^-5?? i dont understand.

Comment: am i doing something wrong??

Comment: @parker You missed a factor of $10$. The approximation should give you an error of the order of $10^{-7}$. You should get the value of $\dfrac1{2 \cdot 2!} - \dfrac1{4 \cdot 4!} + \dfrac1{6 \cdot 6!} - \dfrac1{8 \cdot 8!} \approx 0.23981171461$. The error is less than $\dfrac1{10 \cdot 10!} \approx 2.7 \times 10^{-8}$, since the series alternates.

Comment: ah hah!! i forgot to add a factor of 10. thats why.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\cos(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$,
$1-\cos(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$,
so 
$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$.

Therefore

$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x} dx
&= \int_0^1 dx \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} }{(2n)!} \int_0^1 x^{2n-1} dx\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} }{(2n)!} \frac1{2n} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} }{2n(2n)!}\\
\end{align}
$

This is an alternating series with terms decreasing in absolute value,
so its sum is between any two consecutive terms.

The first two terms are
$\frac1{4}$ and $\frac{-1}{4\cdot 4!} = \frac{-1}{96}$,
so the result is slightly less than $\frac1{4}$.